# How to get Day difference between two dates in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to get difference betwen these below two dates in snowflake.

```
select datediff(
          day,
          Date('Tue Jan 01 1980 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)')::timestamp,
          Date('Tue Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)')::timestamp
       );
```

Comment: The function you mentioned will return the difference in days between the two dates specified. What are you trying to do or what is the problem?

Comment: The key point here is "there problem is not how to get the difference between to dates" problem, but a "how to parse non standard date strings as dates/timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I think the time stamp format is not valid, and the time zone name seems unnecessary and hard to parse.

I wrote a small function to take the first 33 characters from the input and then convert it to a time stamp:

```
create or replace function to_convert_ts ( v varchar )
returns timestamp_tz
as 
$$
select to_timestamp_tz( left(V,33), 'DY MON DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS GMTTZHTZM' )
$$;

select datediff( day, to_convert_ts( 'Tue Jan 01 1980 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)'), 
                to_convert_ts( 'Tue Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)' ) );
-- returns 14610
```

Comment: when i read date column value(2010-02-04 12:00:00.000) then i will getting 'Tue Jan 01 1980 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)' from table

Answer (score 0):

So as noted by Gokhan, this really is a date parsing problem. As can be seen by.

```
select 
    'Tue Jan 01 1980 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)' as date_str_a,
    'Tue Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)' as date_str_b,
    try_to_date(date_str_a) as date_a,
    try_to_date(date_str_b) as date_b,
    datediff(day, date_a, date_b ) as day_diff;
```

should show the date parse fails, the `try_to_date` versions return null if they fail, but the base problem can also be seen with:

```
select date('Tue Jan 01 1980 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)');
```

should give the very error your seeing.

Gokhan, shows how to write a function to do the trim in a hidden, which you can just used out in the open also.
[SUBSTR][1]

Thus

```
select 
    'Tue Jan 01 1980 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)' as date_str_a,
    'Tue Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)' as date_str_b,
    to_timestamp_tz( left(V,33), date_str_a) as tz_a,
    to_timestamp_tz( left(V,33), date_str_b) as tz_b,
    datediff(day, tz_a, tz_b) as day_diff;
```